# Android - RecyclerView freeze after load

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, freeze

I have a RecyclerView and I load item ten by ten from my database by detecting the end of the RecyclerView.
My problem : after loading items, when i scroll, the RecyclerView freeze during 1-2 sec.
I think the problem come from ImageView in each item.
After each load, the last list is added to adapter like this : `arrayAdapter.list.addAll(questions);` and then `arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

My adpater :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Question question = list.get(position);
    holder.tvOwner.setText("Question posée par " + question.ownerUsername);
    holder.tvQuestion.setText(question.question);

    if (question.image != null) {
        holder.questionImage.setImageBitmap(question.image);
        holder.questionImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.questionImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                NavigationMenu nav = (NavigationMenu) context;
                nav.showPictureFullScreen(question.image);
            }
        });
    } else {
        holder.questionImage.setImageBitmap(null);
        holder.questionImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Comment: holder.questionImage.setImageBitmap(question.image); you have to do this on background thread and may be it will be good use cache check here  https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Comment: Something like this ?
`yourImageView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // set the downloaded image here

    }
});`

Comment: Doesn't work with other thread, same problem. It freeze when i scroll

Comment: no use asynch task which i previously mentioned or you can better look for image loading libraries

Comment: Ok it solved thanks to you. How can set solved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Pavan

```
public class SetImageBitmap extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {
    Question q;
    ImageView iv;

    public SetImageBitmap(Question q, ImageView iv) {
        this.q = q;
        this.iv = iv;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return q.image;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```